# How can I do operations on Span<T> in parallel?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, system.memory

I want to do operations on `Span<T>` in parallel but something like this is not legal:

```
void DoSomething(Span<int> buffer, int option1, int option2)
{
   ....... 
}

void ParallelDoSomething(Span<int> buffer)
{
    var size = buffer.Length;
    Parallel.Invoke(() => DoSomething(buffer, 0, size / 2),
        () => DoSomething(buffer, size/2, size)); //not legal
}
```

since compiler complains that: *Cannot use ref, out, or in parameter 'buffer' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, query expression, or local function*

How can I execute in parallel methods which take `Span<T>` as arguments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a working alternative to being unable to pass a Span<T> into lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59605908/11683)

Comment: as a side note: I wonder if the `option1`/`option2` should be removed from `DoSomething()`; that looks like something that should be applied via slice, instead; as a side note, doing so can improve performance: `for(int i = 0 ; i < span.Length; i++)` and `foreach(var val in span)` have JIT optimizations (bounds checks elision), but `for (int i = option1; i < option2; i++)` does **not**

Comment: What about parallelizing the caller of `ParallelDoSomething` instead

Comment: @Mark Gravell, sure option1/ option2 doesn't matter here. I was just trying to quickly change a Mergesort implementation to use stack allocated Spans instead of arrays, because MemoryExtensions.Sort  doesn't help me.

Comment: @Charlieface, there's nothing to parallelize in caller.

Comment: How is `buffer` created?

Comment: @Charlieface, it was something like  Span<int> buffer = stackallock int[size].

Comment: So generate a separate `Span` inside each thread then merge at the end, maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that a `Span<T>` cannot be allowed onto the heap - it is *only* valid on the stack - which means that it can't be either *boxed*, or used as a field on a `class` (or a `struct` except a `ref struct`). This rules out both captured variables and most common forms of `state` parameters.

If you have the luxury of changing the input to be a memory, you can capture the *memory*, and get the span *inside* the lambda body:

```cs
void ParallelDoSomething(Memory<int> memory)
{
    var size = memory.Length;
    Parallel.Invoke(
        () => DoSomething(memory.Span, 0, size / 2),
        () => DoSomething(memory.Span, size/2, size)
    );
}
```

If you can't change the input, you can still do it... by cheating. You can *pin* the existing span, create a memory that covers that pinned data, and use *that* memory just like you would if it had been passed in as a memory. This isn't entirely trivial, since you need to write your own pointer-based memory manager implementation, but: it works. Here's an example from protobuf-net: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protobuf-net.Core/Meta/TypeModel.cs#L767-L789

Or perhaps more conveniently, pin the span and capture the *pointer directly*, noting that the compiler doesn't normally allow this (to prevent the pointer being used by a delegate later), but *since we know the timing semantics*, we can make it happy by duplicating the pointer:

```cs
unsafe void ParallelDoSomething(Span<int> span)
{
    var size = span.Length;
    fixed (int* ptr = span)
    {
        int* evil = ptr; // make the compiler happy
        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => DoSomething(new Span<int>(evil, size), 0, size / 2),
            () => DoSomething(new Span<int>(evil, size), size / 2, size)
        );
    }
}
```

or if we wanted to fix slice the span at the point of input:

```cs
unsafe void ParallelDoSomething(Span<int> span)
{
    var size = span.Length;
    fixed (int* ptr = span)
    {
        int* evil = ptr; // make the compiler happy
        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => DoSomething(new Span<int>(evil, size / 2));
            () => DoSomething(new Span<int>(evil + (size/2), size - (size/2));
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: For flair and style you can even declare a local `DoSomething` method that handles the spanning and hides the `evil` (reducing the chance that `evil` spreads across the land). Less appropriate if you have many `DoSomething`s of course. (Or many `span`s.) Worth noting also, perhaps, that in the drive to reduce copying of memory (which is often why `Span`s are pulled in) this code of course has plenty of hidden allocations, so for the OP it may be worth taking a step back and looking at what we're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yep, agree entirely; I do quite a lot of this kind of parallelism (it drives some key parts of Stack Overflow), but I don't think I've *ever* used the `Parallel` type, precisely because it doesn't have an API surface that is well suited to super-low allocations. I'm a huge fan of the new `static` modifier on lambdas and local functions!

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert yes, I'm trying to reduce both memory copy and allocations, so what would you suggest using instead of Parallel?

Comment: Thank you, I think using Memory isn't an option since the buffer is a stack allocated Span. I was afraid that using unsafe magic would be the only way. You confirmed it, thanks.

Comment: @VladRadu: That is probably food for another question and depends a lot on your actual scenario. If you're operating on more than enough data to make parallelism interesting, a decent question would be whether you really need `Span` at all (as opposed to passing around `Memory`). Conversely, if the data isn't that much but is used to fuel expensive operations that need to be parallelized, copying it is probably not a significant overhead (spinning up threads isn't cheap either, after all, even with `Task`). Given his experience, Marc could probably weigh in on a follow-up question too.