# How to use Parallel.ForEach(..) for Regex.EnumerateMatches(ReadOnlySpan<char>)

Tags: c#, regex, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, .net-7.0

I am using (for speed ofc) the ["RegexSrcGenerator"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-source-generators) and have a regex like this:

```
SpanRegexSrc regex = SpanRegexSrc.CachedRegex;

//and this I use to iterate like this:

foreach(ValueMatch match in regex.EnumerateMatches(myString.AsSpan())
{
    FillValueSlot(_array, startIdx);
    FillValueSlot(_array, startIdx+2);
    FillPadSlot(_array, startIdx+1);
}
```

and `regex.EnumerateMatches(span)` returns a ref-struct enumerator which cannot be used in any async, yield or other such constructs and also cannot be used like that in `Parallel.ForEach` and so on...

I am doing that because I have an array of (eg 100 structs) and these need to be filled BUT:

1 half (50 items) has to be filled with some other data and the computation looks also bit different than the other half (other 50), and I am filling them in this order:

```
    FillValueSlot(_array, 0);
    FillValueSlot(_array, 2);
    FillPadSlot(_array, 1);
```

and so on..

because the "PaddingRegion" is inbetween of the 2 values like:

```
 value[0] -> padding[1] -> value[2]
```

And this I wanted to parallelize, but sadly, since `regex.EnumerateMatches(span)` returns a refstruct, I cannot use that thing inside `Parallel.ForEachAsync()` or `Parallel.ForEach()`

Now the problem with this is, I would like to parallelize that loop because I think this is worth doing it, because this in my mind is an asynchronous operation, why would I need to wait til all "Value-Slots" are filled when I can only fill 2 and then based on those, fill the padding and so on..

I really hope someone of you has an idea for this, because right now it drives me crazy...

Best regards

Edit: to @Theodor Zoulias
Here is my code for the respected array-filling

```
private short FillValueSlot(ValueMatch valueMatch, ref Slot valueSlot)
{
    valueSlot = new(valueMatch.Index, valueMatch.Length, SlotType.Value);
    return length;
}

private short FillPadSlot(Span<Slot> rented, int idx)
{
    ref var valueSlot = ref rented[idx-1];
    ref var padSlot = ref rented[idx];
    int _padStart = valueSlot.OriginalStart + valueSlot.Length;
    int _padLen = rented[idx + 2].OriginalStart - _padStart;
    padSlot = new(padStart, padLen, SlotType.Padding);
    return padLen;
}
```

EDIT: I totally forgot to talk about the specs of my system:

.NET 7, x64, Windows 10, x64

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Hey friend, yea sure:

1) here the link to regex src generation: 
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-source-generators)

Comment: RegexSrcGen is included in .NET 7

Comment: Yea i think they did not yet gave us a chance to use these things in "Multi-Task" aspects like paralell, async and so... very unfortunate cause this is a hot spot in my code which i would like to optimize and i thought rightfully so, cause why not paralellize this?

Comment: Related: [How can I do operations on Span<T> in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66746744/how-can-i-do-operations-on-spant-in-parallel) I don't think that it's possible to parallelize the [`Regex.EnumerateMatches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.enumeratematches) method without resorting to `unsafe` tricks.